# Can't scrape a certain field from a webpage using requests even when that very field is available in page source

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape email address from a webpage. The email address is available in page source (ctrl + u). However, I still can't fetch it using requests. All I get is AttributeError. Any help on this would be appreciated.

[webpage link](https://www.facebook.com/pg/theultimatecollectionco/about/?ref=page_internal)

My current attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.facebook.com/pg/theultimatecollectionco/about/?ref=page_internal"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    try:
        email = soup.select_one("a[href^='mailto:']").get("href")
    except AttributeError: email = ""
    print(email)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `r.text` to confirm the desired field is present?  If the website uses javascript to dynamically add page content, the `requests` module won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is constructed with with help of Javascript, so BeautifulSoup alone cannot see it (`selenium` helps here).

The easiest way is just to grep the page for any `mailto:` hrefs:

```
import re
import html
import requests


link = "https://www.facebook.com/pg/theultimatecollectionco/about/?ref=page_internal"

html_doc = requests.get(link).text
for email in re.findall(r'"mailto:([^"]+)"', html_doc):
    print(html.unescape(email))
```

Prints:

```
support@theultimatecollection.co
```